# GPG: Which password should be used to sign key?

Tags: linux, gnupg, pgp

I am learning to use GPG. I have made a keypair with the password "a" to make sure that I cannot mistype the password. Immediately after making it, I entered

```
gpg --edit-key id
gpg> fpr
gpg> sign
```

GnuPG then prompts for a passphrase, but it prompts i for a key that I made earlier in the day, and not the one I specified by `id`. I enter the passphrase of the key that I want to sign, which you recall is only the letter a. It complains that it is the wrong passphrase. I can see that the passphrase works for other things, like changing the passphrase, and so on.

So why should I use a passphrase for a different key than the one I want to sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why should I use a passphrase for a different key than the one I want to sign?

Because the *entire point* of signing is that the key which makes signatures is different from the key that is being signed. In other words, the `sign` command isn't meant to sign a key using itself (that was automatically done during key generation so there's no separate command for it), its purpose is to sign another person's key with your current default key.

Such an operation only requires the signer's "private" key but not the target's – e.g. if you were signing a coworker's key, it wouldn't make sense to be asked for *their* passphrase.

You should be able to use the `gpg -u` option to select a different private key for key and data signing (e.g. if you want to sign your work key A with your personal key B), but as mentioned, signing a key *with itself* is already done automatically as soon as you add an UID or a subkey (such "subkey-binding signatures" are required by protocol) and therefore there's no point in doing that again manually.